# Wrapper for AG-Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to write a wrapper for AG-GRID using ReactJs. This wrapper would help to use AG-GRID without implementing the logic for fetching data.

Generally with ag-grid implementation user needs to call back-end API to fetch data based on the criteria applied on the ag-grid.

Willing to create a re-usable component which will hide the complexities of handling requests and fetch data. It will help to avoid duplication of the AG-GRID implementation code for two different set of data. User should be able to provide which API needs to call and column definitions to configure the AG-GRID, rest will be taken care by the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

One option could involve creating a parent component (smart component) that handles all high level requests, and then passes the received data down to a child component that contains the grid. This would allow you to, at the very least, decouple the data fetching complexities away from the grid itself.